# Replacing group of characters using regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this:

```
<b.*?n.*? .*?a.*?n.*? .*?e.*?&nbsp;.*? .*? .*? .e.*?t.*?e.*?   .*?   .*? .*? .*?<.r>.*? .*?e.*? .*? .*? .*?l.*?e .*?b.*?e.*?n.*?b.*? .*?  .*?a.*?p.*?t.*? .*?l.*? .*? .*? .*? .*? ..b.*? .*? .*?s.*?   .*?s.*?   .*?>.*? .*?es.*? .*?n.*?t.*?r.*? .*? .*? .*? .n.*?b.*? .*? .*? .*? .*? .*?e.*? .*? .*? .*? .*?t.*?n.*? .*? .*? .*? .*?n.s.. .*?a. .*? <.*?e.e.*? comp.*? .*?<.*? .*?r.*?el.*?&.*?b.*? .*? .*?y.*? ..e.*? .. .*? .*? .*? .*? .*?u.t.*?m..o.*?b.*?r.*?e.*?n.*?o.. .*? .*?s. .*?e.*?o.. .*?r.*?r.*?&.*?b.*? ..b>.*?o.*?s.*? .*?r.*? .*? .*?a..i.*? .*? .*? .*?e.*?in.*? .*? .*? .*? .*? .*? .*? ..b.*? .*? .*? .*?r..i.*?c.*? .*? .*?o.*?<..>.*?
```

Sorry but the `*` is removed from the text above.

I want to be able to replace consecutive appearance of  `.*?` into a single  `.*?`. I tried

```
res = tmp.replaceAll("(\\s\\.\\*\\?)(\\1{2,})","\\s\\.\\*\\?");
```

but it did not work. Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: Does `"(\\s\\.\\*\\?){2,}"` work as your search pattern? Also, I'd guess you don't want the escapes in the replacement.

Comment: I guess `&nbsp;` is just a space, just formatting issue after my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(\s*)(?:\s*\.\*\?){2,}
```

And replace with `$1.*?`. The Group 1 backreference `$1` will keep the initial whitespace before the first `.*?`.

The regex matches:

- `(\s*)` - Group 1: zero or more whitespace symbols
- `(?:\s*\.\*\?){2,}` - two or more sequences of:

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespace symbols
  - `\.` - a literal dot
  - `\*` - a literal asterisk
  - `\?` - a literal `?` symbol

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eJ5sH2/1).

Sample code:

```
String p = "(\\s*)(?:\\s*\\.\\*\\?){2,}"; 
String str = "<b.*?n.*? .*?a.*?n.*? .*?e.*? \\.*? .*? .*? .e.*?t.*?e.*?   .*?   .*? .*? .*?<.r>.*? .*?e.*? .*? .*? .*?l.*?e .*?b.*?e.*?n.*?b.*? .*?  .*?a.*?p.*?t.*? .*?l.*? .*? .*? .*? .*? ..b.*? .*? .*?s.*?   .*?s.*?   .*?>.*? .*?es.*? .*?n.*?t.*?r.*? .*? .*? .*? .n.*?b.*? .*? .*? .*? .*? .*?e.*? .*? .*? .*? .*?t.*?n.*? .*? .*? .*? .*?n.s.. .*?a. .*? <.*?e.e.*? comp.*? .*?<.*? .*?r.*?el.*?&.*?b.*? .*? .*?y.*? ..e.*? .. .*? .*? .*? .*? .*?u.t.*?m..o.*?b.*?r.*?e.*?n.*?o.. .*? .*?s. .*?e.*?o.. .*?r.*?r.*?&.*?b.*? ..b>.*?o.*?s.*? .*?r.*? .*? .*?a..i.*? .*? .*? .*?e.*?in.*? .*? .*? .*? .*? .*? .*? ..b.*? .*? .*? .*?r..i.*?c.*? .*? .*?o.*?<..>.*?"; 
String subst = "$1.*?"; 
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(p, subst));
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/p38YyB)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use loop and replace it. something like follow

```
        String pattern= "(.\*\?\s.\*\?)";
        if(YOURSTRING.matches(pattern)){
            // replace two .*? to one 
        }
        else{ 
            // break your loop   
            }
```

this is not a complete solution. But some basic idea

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
str.replaceAll("\\p{Blank}+", "").replaceAll("[\\.\\*\\?]+", ".*?");
```

**Example:**

```
String str = "abcabcddabceeabcabc";
str = str.replaceAll("[abc]+", "abc");
System.out.println("str = " + str);
```

And the result:

```
str = abcddabceeabc
```